# SSMS Case Statement With Multiple Fields

Tags: case, sql-server-2014, unpivot

I have a case statement to sum, round and label amounts that works fine, but the data ends up in horizontal format (multiple money amounts per record), causing me to do an unpivot in a subsequent statement to format the data vertically (one money amount per record). I would like to accomplish this in one statement if possible. My code is as follows:

```
SELECT
    Field,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE
                  WHEN TYPE = 'Paid Loss'
                  THEN AMOUNT
                  ELSE 0
              END
          ), 2
    ) PAID,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE
                  WHEN TYPE = 'OS'
                  THEN AMOUNT
                  ELSE 0
              END
          ), 2
    ) OS,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE
                  WHEN TYPE <> 'Paid Exp'
                  THEN AMOUNT
                  ELSE 0
              END
          ), 2
    ) INCURRED
FROM dbo.mydatabase
GROUP BY Field;
```

The result is:

```
Field   |PAID |OS  |INCURRED
----------------------------
result1 | 1   | 20 | 10
result2 | 5   | 30 | 15
```

When what I really want is:

```
Field   | DATA_TYPE | AMOUNT
---------------------------
result1 | PAID      | 1
result2 | PAID      | 5
result3 | OS        | 20
result4 | OS        | 30
result5 | INCURRED  | 10
result6 | INCURRED  | 15
```

Keys will be unique so that isn't an issue. Anyone know how to rearrange the CASE so this can be done in one statement? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't this work?

```
SELECT Field, 'PAID' DATA_TYPE, ROUND(SUM(AMOUNT), 2) AMOUNT
FROM dbo.mydatabase
WHERE TYPE = 'Paid Loss'
GROUP BY Field

UNION ALL

SELECT Field, 'OS' DATA_TYPE, ROUND(SUM(AMOUNT), 2) AMOUNT
FROM dbo.mydatabase
WHERE TYPE = 'OS'
GROUP BY Field

UNION ALL

SELECT Field, 'INCURRED' DATA_TYPE, ROUND(SUM(AMOUNT), 2) AMOUNT
FROM dbo.mydatabase
WHERE TYPE <> 'Paid Exp'
GROUP BY Field
```

or even like this:

```
SELECT Field
  , (CASE
     WHEN TYPE IN ('Paid Loss', 'OS') THEN TYPE
     WHEN TYPE <> 'Paid Exp' THEN 'INCURRED'
     END) DATA_TYPE
  , ROUND(SUM(AMOUNT), 2) AMOUNT
FROM dbo.mydatabase
GROUP BY Field
  , (CASE
     WHEN TYPE IN ('Paid Loss', 'OS') THEN TYPE
     WHEN TYPE <> 'Paid Exp' THEN 'INCURRED'
     END) DATA_TYPE
```

Comment: Brilliant! Your second option works like a charm, could not visualize it. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that it worked. Could you please mark my answer. ;)